# Internet Explorer date errors with salesforce but chrome works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, visualforce, apex

I am trying to set up a dynamic field. Which will be generated based on entries of other fields. However whenever i try to submit my form, on Chrome it works perfectly fine, however on internet explorer it doesn't like it and says its an invalid date. Or cannot be converted from text to date.

I am using some Javascript Onblur events to assign the readonly text box dynamically.

```
$j('[id$=MaturityDate]').val(MaturityDate.toLocaleDateString());
```

although the outputted text goes into an approriate m/d/yyyy format, it gives a error on validation.

The output on the textbox is formatted perfectly. It just doesn't work in IE

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is vague but from experience I guess you are using an old jquery, there is a datetime functionality shift around version 1.6. FWIW